# RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 256 elements not 128 pytorch

Tags: python

I am a newbie in PyTorch, GAN, and I don’t have much experience in Python (Although I am a C/C++ programmer).

I have a simple tutorial code for DCGAN for generating fake image, and it was ok when i run the code with “DATASETNAME = ‘MNIST’”. However, when i change the dataset to ‘CIFAR10’, the program produces error related to “running_mean”.

The code is as below

---

```
import torch.nn as nn

def weights_init(module):

    if isinstance(module, nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(module, nn.ConvTranspose2d):
        module.weight.detach().normal_(mean=0., std=0.02)
    elif isinstance(module, nn.BatchNorm2d):
        module.weight.detach().normal_(1., 0.02)
        module.bias.detach().zero_()
    else:
        pass

class View(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, output_shape):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.output_shape = output_shape

    def forward(self, x):
        return x.view(x.shape[0], *self.output_shape)


class Generator(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dataset_name):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        act = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        norm = nn.BatchNorm2d

        if dataset_name == 'CIFAR10':  # Output shape 3x32x32
            model = [nn.Linear(100, 512 * 4 * 4), View([512, 4, 4]), norm(512), act]  # 4x4
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), norm(256), act]  # 8x8
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), norm(128), act]  # 16x16
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 3, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), nn.Tanh()]  # 32x32

        elif dataset_name == 'LSUN':  # Output shape 3x64x64
            model = [nn.Linear(100, 1024 * 4 * 4), View([1024, 4, 4]), norm(1024), act]  # 4x4
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(1024, 512, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), norm(512), act]  # 8x8
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), norm(256), act]  # 16x16
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), norm(128), act]  # 32x32
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 3, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), nn.Tanh()]  # 64x64

        elif dataset_name == 'MNIST':  # Output shape 1x28x28
            model = [nn.Linear(100, 256 * 4 * 4), View([256, 4, 4]), norm(256), act]  # 4x4
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 5, stride=2, padding=2), norm(128), act]  # 7x7
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), norm(64), act]  # 14x14
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 1, 5, stride=2, padding=2, output_padding=1), nn.Tanh()]  # 28x28

        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

        self.model = nn.Sequential(*model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)


class Discriminator(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dataset_name):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        act = nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True, negative_slope=0.2)
        norm = nn.BatchNorm2d

        if dataset_name == 'CIFAR10':  # Input shape 3x32x32
            model = [nn.Conv2d(3, 128, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), act]  # 16x16
            model += [nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(128), act]  # 8x8
            model += [nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(256), act]  # 4x4
            model += [nn.Conv2d(512, 1, 4, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), nn.Sigmoid()]  # 1x1

        elif dataset_name == 'LSUN':  # Input shape 3x64x64
            model = [nn.Conv2d(3, 128, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), act]  # 128x32x32
            model += [nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(128), act]  # 256x16x16
            model += [nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(256), act]  # 512x8x8
            model += [nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(512), act]  # 1024x4x4
            model += [nn.Conv2d(1024, 1, 4), nn.Sigmoid()]  # 1x1x1

        elif dataset_name == 'MNIST':  # Input shape 1x28x28
            model = [nn.Conv2d(1, 64, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), act]  # 14x14
            model += [nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(128), act]  # 7x7
            model += [nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(256), act]  # 4x4
            model += [nn.Conv2d(256, 1, 4, bias=False), nn.Sigmoid()]  # 1x1

        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

        self.model = nn.Sequential(*model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import os
    from torchvision.transforms import Compose, Normalize, Resize, ToTensor
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
    #from models import Discriminator, Generator, weights_init
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from time import time
    from tqdm import tqdm
    from torchvision.utils import save_image
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
    

    BETA1, BETA2 = 0.5, 0.99
    BATCH_SIZE = 16
    DATASET_NAME = 'CIFAR10'
    DEVICE = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu:0')
    EPOCHS = 1
    ITER_REPORT = 10
    LATENT_DIM = 100
    LR = 2e-4
    N_D_STEP = 1
    ITER_DISPLAY = 500

    IMAGE_DIR = './GAN/checkpoints/'+DATASET_NAME+'/Image'
    MODEL_DIR = './GAN/checkpoints/'+DATASET_NAME+'/Model'
    
    if DATASET_NAME == 'CIFAR10':
        IMAGE_SIZE = 32
        OUT_CHANNEL = 3
        from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10
        transforms = Compose([ToTensor(), Normalize(mean=[0.5], std=[0.5])])
        dataset = CIFAR10(root='./datasets', train=True, transform=transforms, download=True)
    elif DATASET_NAME == 'LSUN':
        IMAGE_SIZE = 64
        OUT_CHANNEL = 3
        from torchvision.datasets import LSUN
        transforms = Compose([Resize(64), ToTensor(), Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])
        dataset = LSUN(root='./datasets/LSUN', classes=['bedroom_train'], transform=transforms)
    elif DATASET_NAME == 'MNIST':
        IMAGE_SIZE = 28
        OUT_CHANNEL = 1
        from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
        transforms = Compose([ToTensor(), Normalize(mean=[0.5], std=[0.5])])
        dataset = MNIST(root='./datasets', train=True, transform=transforms, download=True)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=0, shuffle=True)

    D = Discriminator(DATASET_NAME).apply(weights_init).to(DEVICE)
    G = Generator(DATASET_NAME).apply(weights_init).to(DEVICE)
    print(D, G)
    criterion = nn.BCELoss()

    optim_D = torch.optim.Adam(D.parameters(), lr=LR, betas=(BETA1, BETA2))
    optim_G = torch.optim.Adam(G.parameters(), lr=LR, betas=(BETA1, BETA2))

    list_D_loss = list()
    list_G_loss = list()
    total_step = 0

    st = time()
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for data in tqdm(data_loader):
            total_step += 1
            real, label = data[0].to(DEVICE), data[1].to(DEVICE)
            z = torch.randn(BATCH_SIZE, LATENT_DIM).to(DEVICE)

            fake = G(z)

            real_score = D(real)
            fake_score = D(fake.detach())

            D_loss = 0.5 * (criterion(fake_score, torch.zeros_like(fake_score).to(DEVICE))
                            + criterion(real_score, torch.ones_like(real_score).to(DEVICE)))
            optim_D.zero_grad()
            D_loss.backward()
            optim_D.step()
            list_D_loss.append(D_loss.detach().cpu().item())
            
            if total_step % ITER_DISPLAY == 0:
                #(BatchSize, Channel*ImageSize*ImageSize)-->(BatchSize, Channel, ImageSize, ImageSize)
                fake = fake.view(BATCH_SIZE, OUT_CHANNEL, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)
                real = real.view(BATCH_SIZE, OUT_CHANNEL, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE)
                save_image(fake, IMAGE_DIR + '/{}_fake.png'.format(epoch + 1), nrow=4, normalize=True)
                save_image(real, IMAGE_DIR + '/{}_real.png'.format(epoch + 1), nrow=4, normalize=True)
            
            if total_step % N_D_STEP == 0:
                fake_score = D(fake)
                G_loss = criterion(fake_score, torch.ones_like(fake_score))
                optim_G.zero_grad()
                G_loss.backward()
                optim_G.step()
                list_G_loss.append(G_loss.detach().cpu().item())

                if total_step % ITER_REPORT == 0:
                    print("Epoch: {}, D_loss: {:.{prec}} G_loss: {:.{prec}}"
                          .format(epoch, D_loss.detach().cpu().item(), G_loss.detach().cpu().item(), prec=4))

    torch.save(D.state_dict(), '{}_D.pt'.format(DATASET_NAME))
    torch.save(G.state_dict(), '{}_G.pt'.format(DATASET_NAME))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(range(0, len(list_D_loss)), list_D_loss, linestyle='--', color='r', label='Discriminator loss')
    plt.plot(range(0, len(list_G_loss) * N_D_STEP, N_D_STEP), list_G_loss, linestyle='--', color='g',
             label='Generator loss')
    plt.xlabel('Iteration')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('Loss.png')

    print(time() - st)
```

---

The error seems to come from Discriminator .forward as follows:

```
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in 
71 fake = G(z)
72
?> 73 real_score = D(real)
74 fake_score = D(fake.detach())
75

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in call(self, *input, **kwargs)
491 result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
492 else:
?> 493 result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
494 for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
495 hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

in forward(self, x)
87
88 def forward(self, x):
?> 89 return self.model(x)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in call(self, *input, **kwargs)
491 result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
492 else:
?> 493 result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
494 for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
495 hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py in forward(self, input)
90 def forward(self, input):
91 for module in self._modules.values():
?> 92 input = module(input)
93 return input
94

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in call(self, *input, **kwargs)
491 result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
492 else:
?> 493 result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
494 for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
495 hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py in forward(self, input)
81 input, self.running_mean, self.running_var, self.weight, self.bias,
82 self.training or not self.track_running_stats,
?> 83 exponential_average_factor, self.eps)
84
85 def extra_repr(self):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in batch_norm(input, running_mean, running_var, weight, bias, training, momentum, eps)
1695 return torch.batch_norm(
1696 input, weight, bias, running_mean, running_var,
-> 1697 training, momentum, eps, torch.backends.cudnn.enabled
1698 )
1699

RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 256 elements not 128
```

Can anyone tell me what is this error about? It seems to come from size setting of something in the model, but that’s all I can guess.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
model += [nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 5, stride=2, padding=2, bias=False), norm(128), act]  # 8x8
```

it is a batch normalization input error it should be 256 instead.